# Excel inserts no data using OPENROWSET when logged in as any account but my local account

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, export, openrowset

I am trying to export data to Excel from SQL Server via a c# winforms application.  The application is running on a windows domain environment.

Here is the query:

```
string exportQuery = @"INSERT INTO OpenRowSet('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\temp\ExportedCategoryTotals.xls; HDR=YES' , 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] AS f') " +

"SELECT category AS Category, counter AS Counter, date AS Date, locationname AS Location FROM categoryData " +

"WHERE locationName IN ('" + locationBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')" +
                        " AND date BETWEEN CAST('" + startDate + "' AS DATETIME) 

AND CAST('" + endDate + "' AS DATETIME) ORDER BY locationName, date, counter DESC";
```

When I run this query as myself (logged into my user account on the domain) (inside of my c# application), everything runs as it should and the data is exported to excel from SQL Server.

When I run this query as anyone else.  The file contains no data.  There is no error from the compiler.

Ive tried creating logins that match the ad user of the current user, and assigning a credential of the domain admin account for that user.  But same result.

Using Procmon reveals:

[image]

I'd be grateful for some assistance.

Comment: Does the SQL Server Service account have access to `C:\Temp`? Also, concatenating your values like you have does is rarely a good idea; it'll most likely be open to injection.

Comment: Any chance it thinks the spreadsheet is already open:?

Comment: @ Larnu: I have to concatenate the values because OpenRowSet does not allow for parameterised queries

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't be parametrising where possible still, or making use of `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: @Larnu: Which account are you referring to sorry?  Is it listed in the list of roles?

Comment: When you do any type of interaction with the a local, or even network, directory, the account that accesses the location will be that of the service account. That's the account that the data engine is running under.

Comment: What is the name of the account that I have to grant permissions to `c:\temp` to?

Comment: In terms of the account that is running the query, in this case (I assume) the application login, it'll need permission to perform `BULK` operations. Does it have permission to do so as well?

Comment: When you say "the application login", do you mean the ad account of the current user logged in?  How do i assign the `BULK` permissions?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions) on how to assign the permissions. And only you, or the person who designed the application, will know under what login the application connects the SQL Server as. I don't have access to your applications configuration settings to tell you that.

Comment: Ok, I didnt understand what you meant by "application login".  You mean the account the application uses to connect to the database.  Thanks.  I'll have a look at the docs.

Comment: Ok I've assigned Bulk operations permissions to the application login and still no joy :-/

Comment: You should include the C# code that executes this query.  Also, does the application connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication (integrated security - i.e., the user running the app), or some other method (SQL user, etc)?